# SOAP Authentication Through cURL PHP Returns "HTTP GET method not implemented" 500 error

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

So I am working on SOAP request using PHP cURL. I want to invoke operations but before that I want to test the authentication part. Below is my code:

```
$username = 'myusername';
$password = 'mypassword';
$host = 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx';

$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                      
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username.":".$password)
));
curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'xxxxx/x.x');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
$return = curl_exec($process);
print_r($return);

curl_close($process);
```

I need to use base64 username/password. I found how to do this on some other question. But when I do `print_r($return)` I received

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: xxxxx/x.x Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 883 Connection: close SOAP-ENV:Client HTTP GET method not implemented
```

I am not sure what this error means plus I could not found much questions on this kind of error. Perhaps somebody could explain me what is going on here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating that the service you are trying to reach does not have the HTTPGET functionality implemented. Without knowing what you are trying to reach and documentation of the api you are trying to reach or description of what you are trying to do there is no way to help with the error.

Normally an error 500 is for an internal server error and not for a not implemented error that you are receiving. Below or descriptions of response code standards.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html